# combining threading with queue. snowflake

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, python-multithreading

a newbie over here!!!

had to start putting together a program that uses thread and queue to connect to snowflake a run queries stored in a csv file.

currently have a working program that creates threads but due to being more that 400 it starts having some disconnections. it should run more than 4k queries.

here's my current code, if someone could help me out completing this would be great!!.
already read a lot of options but have not been able to make it work as intended (I already used queue, threadpoolexecutor, sqlalchemy)

```
# First import the threading module to support this functionality
import threading, queue
from csv import DictReader

# Second import the Snowflake module
import snowflake.connector as sf

def sfConnect (
    sfPswd = 'psw',
    sfUser = 'user',
    sfAccount = 'account'
) :
    import getpass

    # Request user password if not provided already
    if sfPswd == '' :
        import getpass
        sfPswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')

    # Test the connection to Snowflake
    try:
        sfConnection = sf.connect(
            user=sfUser,
            password=sfPswd,
            account=sfAccount
        )
        sfq = sfConnection.cursor()
        sfq.close()
        sfConnection.close()
    except:
        print('Connection failed. Check credentials')

    sfConnection = sf.connect(
        user=sfUser,
        password=sfPswd,
        account=sfAccount
    )

    print('Connection established')

    return sfConnection

# Define the threads class called sfExecutionThread.
# This class is an object which stores all the necessary details for the thread.
# Specifically, we include a threadID so that we can identify individual threads.
# When executed, each thread will announce that it is starting, execute sfExecuteInSnowflake(),
# then announce that it is exiting.
class sfExecutionThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, sqlQuery):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.sqlQuery = sqlQuery
   def run(self):
      print('Starting {0}'.format(self.threadID))
      sfExecuteInSnowflake(self.sqlQuery)
      print('Exiting {0}'.format(self.threadID))

# Define the function that will be executed within each thread
def sfExecuteInSnowflake (
    sfQuery,
    sfRole = 'role',
    sfWarehouse = 'COMPUTE_WH',
    sfDatabase = 'db'
) :
    # Establish connection
    ## Make sure you insert the right login credentials below.
    sfConnection = sfConnect(sfUser = 'user', sfAccount = 'account', sfPswd = 'psw')

    # Use role defined in function input
    sfConnection.cursor().execute('USE ROLE {0}'.format(sfRole))

    # Use warehouse defined in function input
    sfConnection.cursor().execute('USE WAREHOUSE {0}'.format(sfWarehouse))

    # Use database defined in function input
    sfConnection.cursor().execute('USE DATABASE {0}'.format(sfDatabase))    

    # Increase the session timeout if desired
    sfConnection.cursor().execute("ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG = 'threadtest'")

    # Execute the query sfQuery in Snowflake
    sfConnection.cursor().execute(sfQuery)

# Define the list of variables which determine the data that will be loaded

with open('result.csv') as csvfile:
    dict_reader = DictReader(csvfile)
    variablesList = list(dict_reader)

# Define an empty list to populate with query statements
queryStatements = []

# Loop through the members of variablesList and construct the query statements
# Use .format() to replace the {0} variable querytxt
for member in variablesList:
  queryStatements.append(
    '''{0};'''.format(member['QUERYTXT'])
  )

# Create the empty list of threads
threads = []

# Define a counter which will be used as the threadID
counter = 0

# Loop through each statement in the queryStatements list,
# adding the sfExecutionThread thread to the list of threads
# and incrementing the counter by 1 each time.
for statement in queryStatements:
    threads.append(sfExecutionThread(counter, statement))
    counter += 1

# Execute the threads
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
```

Comment: You want to run 400/4000 queries on Snowflake in parallel? Why? It might make more sense to serialize them

Comment: You can do this with Snowflake, but you're going to need a high multi-cluster value to handle the concurrency.  Otherwise, they are just going to end up queuing up on the Snowflake warehouse.

Comment: thank you for your answers, its part of a POC. simulating workload into snowflake.
I already created tasks and other tasks that take care of enabling/disabling at time intervals. but they get stuck. I dont need them to run all at the same time, but to at least being put on queue so it can be determined which size whit as many clusters would be required.